# addView not displaying after removeAllViews on custom view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-custom-view

I'm building a custom view, sort of like a custom bar chart. I'm extending the `LinearLayout` for this one. The custom view then populates the views from data. Problem is, whenever I want the views to be 'refreshed', I am calling `removeAllViews()` and similar methods, so the custom view layout is in clean slate, then to repopulate the data, I call `addView()`, but child views don't show up. Reason why I need to call `removeAllViews` is for the child views to not duplicate in the custom views.

These are some of the snippets from my custom view, I also implemented `onLayout()` so whenever I display the custom views I get proper heights for layouting purposes. `BarChartData` is just a model class for the data that should be displayed in this custom view:

```
public void setChartData(BarChartData data) {
    this.chartData = data;
    addBarDataToUi();
}


void addBarDataToUi() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Add bar data to UI called");
    if (chartData != null) {
        //this.removeAllViews(); -> first one I tried, no luck, not displaying views after `addView`
        //this.removeAllViewsInLayout(); -> tried this too but no luck
        this.removeViewsInLayout(0, this.getChildCount()); // again, to no avail :(
        for (int i = 0, count = chartData.getItemCount(); i < count; i++) {
            addBarItemDataUi(chartData.getItemByPos(i));
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Child count: " + this.getChildCount());
    }
}

void addBarItemDataUi(BarItemData data) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.bar_chart_item, this, false);
    FrameLayout mainLayout = (FrameLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.bar_chart_item_main_layout);
    //TextView topText = new TextView(getContext());
    TextView topText = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.bar_chart_item_top_text);
    TextView bottomText = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.bar_chart_item_bottom_text);

    topText.setText(String.valueOf(data.percentage));
    bottomText.setText(data.title);
    mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(data.backgroundColor);
    Log.d(TAG, "Height: " + this.getMeasuredHeight() + ", Top text height: " + topText.getMeasuredHeight());
    int heightRel = (int) (data.getPercentageFractal() * (double) this.getMeasuredHeight());

    mainLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, heightRel));

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
    params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

    layout.setLayoutParams(params);

    this.addView(layout);

}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    Log.d(TAG, "On layout..");
    if (chartData != null) {
        addBarDataToUi();
    }
}
```

Well, I have searched this problem, there are very few that came up, almost the same scenario and problem, but I think they have not resolved their problems about addView after removeAllViews.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that by calling the `removeAllViews()` function inside the `addBarDataToUi()` which is inside `onLayout()` when the function gets called by `setChartData(BarChartData data)` it adds the child views which triggers the `onLayout()` function which calls `addBarDataToUi()` and removes view and such in some kind of constant loop. The android documentation says to

> avoid using `removeAllViews()` inside `onDraw()` or any related function
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeAllViews()

Which I'm assuming might also include the onLayout() function as well.

My best suggestion is moving your `removeAllViews()` function call to inside your `setChartData(BarChartData data)` function just before you call `addBarDataToUi()`

Hope it helps

Comment: Hmm, i also thought that `onLayout()` is a related function, just tried removing `addBarDataToUi()` from `onLayout()`

Comment: Thanks for a hint. I found that `addOnLayoutChangeListener` run from a thread doesn't always redraw a recreated layout (I added views inside it). But all parameters were right. When rotating a device, changes became visible. Then I called another method: `runOnUiThread` and inside it `layout.post(new Runnable ...)`.